# How can I sort through an array of objects when a button is clicked to display a category?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a homework of making an eCommerce website that has a requirement of being able to sort products by category, and price and then display those that match in the website

I created the products objects and also got it display them into my website how I wanted them but still no luck with the sorting with what I have tried so I was wondering if anybody had a method to do this

```
let products = [{
        name: '919 Shirt',
        price: 30,
        category: 'Clothing',
        description: 'Cotton Shirt from S.N.M with his original design',
        url: `https://i.imgur.com/1UolmmD.png`
    }, {
        name: 'NC Baseball Cap',
        price: 19.99,
        category: 'Clothing',
        description: 'Baseball cap from S.N.M commerating NC',
        url: `https://i.imgur.com/XgQW8sZ.png`,
    },
    {
        name: 'Martin Commemorative Shirt',
        price: 29.99,
        category: 'Clothing',
        description: `Design by S.N.M`,
        url: `https://i.imgur.com/w6tCDHX.png`,
    },
    {
        name: `American DJ Pro Event Table II Foldable Portable DJ Booth`,
        price: 389.99,
        category: 'Event Equipment',
        description: `Cool Table for events.`,
        url: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71s5FCjIkoL._SX425_.jpg`,
    },
    {
        name: `Rockville ROCKFORCE 384 Channel Light/Fog DMX Lighting Controller`,
        price: 9995.95,
        category: `Event Equipment`,
        description: `Professional Event lighting controller from Rockville`,
        url: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71%2Bc4Qvj1iL._SX679_.jpg`,
    },
    {
        name: `JBL Powered 3-Way High Directivity Line Array`,
        price: 55775.99,
        category: `Event Equipment`,
        description: `Array of JBL speakers for events`,
        url: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511XZRVO22L._SX425_.jpg`,
    },
    {
        name: `VTX M22 Dual 12" Professional Stage Monitor`,
        price: 3500.99,
        category: `Event Equipment`,
        description: `Professional stage monitor.`,
        url: 'https://www.springtree.net/image/cache/data/jm22-900x900.jpg',
    },
    {
        name: `JBL VRX932LAP`,
        description: `12 in. Two-Way Powered Line Array Loudspeaker System`,
        price: 2699.99,
        category: `Event Equipment`,
    },
    {
        name: `JBL VRX918SP`,
        description: `18 in. High Power Powered Flying Subwoofer`,
        price: 1999.99,
        category: `Event Equipment`
    },
    {
        name: `VRX915M`,
        description: `15 in. Two-Way Stage Monitor`,
        price: 1699.99,
        category: `Event Equipment`
    },
    {
        name: `The Face Off - Drake Vs. Meek Mill And Beyonce Vs. Rihanna`,
        description: `Charlotte, NC`,
        price: 22.50,
        category: `Event Ticket`
    },
    {
        name: `Mozzy - Internal Affairs Tour`,
        description: `Charlotte, NC`,
        price: 18.00,
        category: `Event Ticket`,

    }
]

function Display() {
    let allProductsHTML = '';
    const productGrid = document.getElementById('productGrid');
    products.forEach(product => {
        const productHTML = `
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <figure class="card card-product">
                <article class="img-wrap"><img src="${product.url}"></article>
                <div class="bottom--section">
                <figcaption class="info-wrap">
                        <h4 class="title">${product.name}</h4>
                        <p class="desc">${product.description}</p>
                </figcaption>
                <section class="bottom-wrap">
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right">Order Now</a> 
                    <div class="price-wrap h5">
                        <span class="price-new">$${product.price}</span> <del class="price-old">$${product.price*2}</del>
                    </div> <!-- price-wrap.// -->
                </section> <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
                </div
            </figure>
        </div> <!-- col // -->    
        `
        allProductsHTML += productHTML;
    });
    productGrid.innerHTML = allProductsHTML;
}
Display();
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to group by category?

Comment: Where is the sorting code that you tried? Please show your attempt even if it does not work. We can help you improve it and find mistakes, but we won't do your homework.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: [mcve] will help you in editing this if your question gets closed or voted down or gets an answer you can’t make use of easily. The more narrow your question, the more likely [someone can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects-by-property) and others with the same experience in coding.